# Create a countdown timer

Tags: python, android

Can you make me a countdown timer that includes minutes/seconds/milliseconds?

Here is the current code, only minutes/seconds

```py
import time

def countdown(time_sec):
    while time_sec:
        mins, secs = divmod(time_sec, 60)

        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        time_sec -= 1
    print("stop")

countdown(180)
```

Comment: Why did you tag this `android` and `lua`?

Answer (score 0):

If we want millisecond accuracy, we need to first multiply the number of seconds passed by 1000 to get the amount of milliseconds, then repeat the divmod calculation to get the amount of minutes, seconds and milliseconds in the current time, and reduce the sleep length (in Windows, very short sleep calls aren't very accurate, so this might not work as expected):

```py
import time

def countdown(time_sec):

    time_msec = time_sec*1000 # Turn received seconds into milliseconds
    
    while time_msec:
        
        mins, secs = divmod(time_msec, 60000) # Number of milliseconds in a minute
        secs, msecs = divmod(secs, 1000) # Number of milliseconds in a second

        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}.{:03d}'.format(mins, secs, msecs) # Added another field to the format

        print(timeformat, end='\r')

        time.sleep(1/1000) # Reduced sleep length

        time_msec -= 1

    print("stop")

countdown(180)
```

This now prints:

```
02:57.292
```